# What is the best method for creating a custom LISTSERV page?

Tags: php, listserv

I have LISTSERV installed and have many lists. There are three different domains used in my LISTSERV installation. I am wanting to create a web page (preferably in PHP) for each domain that will display all the lists that fall in that domain and allow the user to check all the lists they want to be subscribed to (or uncheck to unsubscribe).

I suspect that integrating LISTSERV with Oracle would be the best way to do this, but wondering if there is a better way.